# Flume-ng hdfs security

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera, flume, flume-ng

I'm new in hadoop and Flume NG and I need some help.
I don't understand how hdfs security implemented.

Here are lines from configuration from Flume User Guide:

`# properties of hdfs-Cluster1-sink
agent_foo.sinks.hdfs-Cluster1-sink.type = hdfs
agent_foo.sinks.hdfs-Cluster1-sink.hdfs.path = hdfs://namenode/flume/webdata`

Does it mean that anyone who knows my hdfs path can write any data to my hdfs?

Answer (score 1):

The question is from some time ago, but I'll try to answer it for any other developer dealing with Flume and HDFS security.

Flume's HDFS sink just need the *endpoint* where the data is going to be persisted. It such an endpoint is secured or not, it depends entirely on Hadoop, not in Flume.

Hadoop ecosystem has several tools and system for implementing security, but focusing on those *native* elements, we talk about the authentication and authorization methods.

The authentication is based on Kerberos, and as any other auth mechanism, it is the process of determining whether someone or something is, in fact, who or what it is declared to be. So, by using auth it is not enough by knowing a HDFS user name, but you have to demostrate you own such a user by previously authenticating against Kerberos and obtaining a ticket. Authentication may be pasword-based or keytab-based; you can see the keytabs as "certificate files" containing the authentication keys.

The authorization can be implemented at file system, by deciding which permissions has any folder or file within HDFS. Thus, is a certaing file has only 600 permissions, then only its owner will be able to read or write it. Other authorization mechanisms like Hadoop ACLs can be used.

Being said that, if you have a look to the [Flume sink](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#hdfs-sink), you'll see that there is a couple of parameters about Kerberos:

- hdfs.kerberosPrincipal    –   Kerberos user principal for accessing secure HDFS
- hdfs.kerberosKeytab   –   Kerberos keytab for accessing secure HDFS

In Kerberos terminology, a principal is a unique identity to which Kerberos can assign tickets. Thus, for each enabled user at HDFS you will need a principal registered in Kerberos. The keytab, as previously said, is a container for the authentication keys a certain principal owns.

Thus, if you want to secure your HDFS then install Kerberos, create principals and keytabs for each enabled user and configure the HDFS sink properly. In addition, change the permissions appropriately in your HDFS.